# Is it right to say "after which time" as in the sentence mentioned herein?

Tags: which-who

"Fermentation took place in an incubator at 28C for 24 hours, **after which time** the grains were separated from the medium with a plastic sieve and plunged in a fresh medium"

Comment: The usage is OK @Fifi Blu. Another example: 'He usually works in the library for 5 to 7 hours, *after which time* he feels mentally tired and needs a break.' Of course you can substitute 'after which time' with 'after which' which is the more common way to write your sentence. I think the use of 'time' specifically gives importance to the amount of time taken in that process.

Comment: Yes, it's fine. "which" has "24 hours" as antecedent, so we understand that after 24 hours (time) the grains were separated ...". I've bracketed "time" because it is not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Fifi, my writing ear instructs to break the sentence to two sentences:

Fermentation took place in an incubator at 28C for 24 hours. Afterward, the grains were separated from the medium with a plastic sieve and then plunged into a fresh medium.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

"Then the grains were separated from the medium with a plastic sieve and plunged into a fresh medium" a fine choice as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Network, Glenda. Please note that this is not a typical discussion forum. Your posts here are meant to be authoritative **answers**, preferably citing reputable sources, not contributions to a discussion. If you have something to add to a previous answer, you should edit the answer and add it in, rather than post a separate answer. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and take the [tour] to familiarise yourself with how the site works.